# Merge polygon based on other line shapefile PostGIS

Tags: postgis, shapefile, arcobjects, merge, dissolve

I have a polygon shapefile and a line shapefile. I would like to merge two polygons which shares the same border along with line shape. Finally the line should be removed in polygon shapefile.

In below sample, A&B polygons should be merged and C&D, E&F, G&H so on...

[image: Polygon and Line shapefiles]

If any easy solution available other than PostGIS, then please provide your views.

Comment: Are there no attributes in common between C/D or A/B?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than thinking about merging A/B and trying to avoid merging A/E, merge them all together into a single lake polygon (I'm hoping here your data model does at least include a unique code for the lakes) with ST_Union. Then, use ST_DumpRings() to get just the rings. Then add the skeleton lines for just that lake to the collection. Then use ST_Polygonize() to build up the polygons formed by the lake boundaries and skeleton lines.